# How do I calculate the frequency of a primary key of table 1 in table 2 and join the results with table 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

I'm a complete beginner who started creating an app in Ruby on Rails for a research project a few days ago, with virtually no coding experience (I have a background in Life Science).

I have a table that lists patients, including their relevant clinical information. Each patient has a unique patient identifier (UPI), which serves as the primary key. In another table, I've listed every blood product each patient has received. In yet another table, I'm recording all complications. In the app, I want to display the following information in one table:

- The UPI of the patient.
- The diagnosis.
- The number of blood products they have received.
- Whether or not they had any complications (yes/no).

I was able to get the app to show a table with all UPIs and their respective diagnoses. However, I've spent the entire day trying to display the number of blood products. I haven't even started looking into the data on complications. I've tried different methods that I found by reading through tutorials and other posts here, but I never got it to work. The last thing I tried was to use .group.count on the table and attempted to join that with my patient table. However, I ended up with a hash, and I couldn't figure out how to join it with the patient table or relate the hash categories to match the UPI from the patient table to display the correct data for each patient.

**The Code:**

```
class BloodProductCount < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :patient

    def bpcount
      @bpcount = BloodProduct.group(:upi).count
      @bpcount.each_value do |key, value|
        key == patient.upi
      end
    end 
end
```

```
class DataController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @patient = Patient.all
    @antibody = Antibody.all
    @blood_product = BloodProduct.all
    @case = Case.all
    @bpcount = BloodProductCount.all
  end
end
```

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>UPI</th>
    <th>Diagnose</th>
    <th>Anzahl EKs</th>
    <th>Antikörper</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @patient.each do |pt| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= pt.upi %></td>
        <td><%= pt.diagnose %></td>
        <td><%= @bpcount %></td>
        <td>placeholder</td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Output generated:**

```
UPI     Diagnose    Anzahl EKs  Antikörper
1   SCD     #<BloodProductCount::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000001e6425e1c38>  placeholder
2   SCD     #<BloodProductCount::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000001e6425e1c38>  placeholder
```

What I did in the class `BloodProductCount` was just a random attempt to generate what I was looking for. I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: Could you please add your `db/schema.rb` to the question?

Comment: "I haven't even started looking into the data on complications." you should really ask this as a separate question. The scope here is wide enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BloodProductCount` attempt is not very close. You created a new class that inherits from `ApplicationRecord`, so this is a new model that Rails expects to be backed by another table. This is not the case.

But the approach in the class is very close.

You could put basically the same code into the `DataController` or add it as a method to some model or another helper class. Up to you.

I will demostrate it here as if it was in the controller for simplicity.

```rb
class DataController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @patient = Patient.all
    @bpcount = BloodProduct.group(:upi).count # moved as-is from BloodProductCount
  end
end
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>UPI</th>
    <th>Diagnose</th>
    <th>Anzahl EKs</th>
    <th>Antikörper</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @patient.each do |pt| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= pt.upi %></td>
        <td><%= pt.diagnose %></td>
        <!-- See difference here. This is how you access values of a hash -->
        <td><%= @bpcount[pt.upi] || 0 %></td>
        <!-- defaulting to 0 because if there are no bloodproducts,
             the upi will be missing from the hash. -->
        <td>placeholder</td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: While you could do this it adds an additional database query and mungling the data together like this just feels dirty.

Comment: This approach will work for a very simple case it breaks down at scale as you would have to ensure that limits and paging give you the right results in both data sets.

Comment: Yes of course, but the question was from someone "with virtually no coding experience". So I tried to keep the answer as simple as possible. No point for premature optimization in a pet project. I started this answer with SQL and Arel but then reverted to a simple answer. I do believe that both of our answers provide value.

Comment: Hi! Thank you, your version did work for me and thanks for keeping my lack of experience in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have these two models:

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blood_products
end

class BloodProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

To get a count of BloodProduct's per Patient you can join the other table and select a count of the rows:

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blood_products

  def self.with_blood_product_count
    left_joins(:blood_products)
       .group(:id)
       .select(
         # patients.*
         arel_table[Arel.star], 
         # COUNT(blood_products.id) AS blood_product_count
         BloodProduct.arel_table[:id] # you can use * instead on Postgres
                     .count
                     .as("blood_product_count")
       )
  end
end

@patients = Patient.with_blood_product_count
@patients.each { |p| puts "#{p.upi}: #{p.blood_product_count}" }
```

If you want to optimize this so that its not calculated for every page load you could add [a counter-cache to the blood_products assocation](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/19/activerecords-counter-cache.html).

Comment: This same approach is how you could deal with complications. Join that table and select a count and process it into a yes/no in Rails or use a subquery to check if any rows exist and cast it into a boolean or string.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work, but the approach posted above did.